# Symfony 2: How to give access to users according to their roles

Tags: php, symfony

I have created an entity in order to manage all users and give them specific authorization.

This is the entity I have created. I show you only the part related to the roles.

```
...

private $roles = array();   

public function setRoles(array $roles) {
$this->roles = $roles;
return $this;
}


  public function getRoles() {

 $roles = $this->roles;

// Ensure we having something
     $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';         
return array_unique($roles);
 }
```

This is the file security.yml

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Now, If I login with an user having ROLE_ADMIN I get an error: **ACCESS DENIED**.
I am new to Symfony and probably I did not code correctly the roles in the entity.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked the profiler to make sure you have the role you think you do?

Comment: Have you read the different steps in the [security cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) ? It's hard to figure out your issue without complementary information. If you go in your database, is the role related to your account 'ADMIN' or 'ROLE_ADMIN' ?

Comment: Hi, yes I read the security part of the online documentation and in the table the role related to admin is ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: If you are running in the dev environment and have the debug toolbar then the 2nd option from the right on the toolbar will show who you are logged in as. If you click on this it will show you what roles they have. Check this to see if you are logged in as the correct user and that they have the ROLE_ADMIN role.

Comment: Hi, I had a look at the toolbar. I am logged correct, but the role is ROLE_USER instead of ROLE_ADMIN...as I wrote before in the database admin has ROLE_ADMIN AS role

Comment: See if this helps. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/brmz/in-memory-style-user-authentication-and-authorisation

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the error. The var private should not be an array.